# Is there a sequence $a_n$ decreasing to $1$ such that $\sum n^{-a_n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does there exist a decreasing sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 1$ for which the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{a_n}}$$ converges? Inspiration: I was a bit surprised to learn that [this series diverges for $a_n = 1+\frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/320144/167197). Now I'm curious if anything strange happens here, if there is a sequence $\{a_n\}$ that decreases to $1$ "slowly enough" to make the series converge. Otherwise we get a slight generalization of what we know about $p$-series from this.

Comment: Such examples are in the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889898/42969 – Can we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @MartinR You're right they're the same question. One should be marked as a duplicate of the other eventually. This is kinda a neat fact though—is there not a more popular (hot?) question about it somewhere on MathSE? … also since such a sequence exists I'm tempted the ask the harder question: for *which* sequences does the series converge?

Answer (score 4):

Let $$a_n = 1 + \frac{2\ln\ln n}{\ln n}\text{ for }n\geq 3.$$
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 1$. To see that the series converges, note that for $n\geq 3$, we have $$\frac{1}{n^{a_n}} = \frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{2\ln\ln n}{\ln n}}} = \frac{1}{n\cdot e^{2\ln\ln n}} = \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}.$$ Thus, we have $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{a_n}} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}.$$
Consider this improper integral
$$\int_{3}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x(\ln x)^2}=\int_3^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}(\ln x)}{(\ln x)^{2}}=\int_{\ln 3}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{u^{2}}<+\infty.$$
It follows that $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}<+\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

For $2^{k}<n\le 2^{k+1}$ let $a_n=1+k^{-1/2}.$ Then $$\sum_{n=2^{k}+1}^{2^{k+1}}{1\over n^{a_n}}\le {2^k\over 2^{k(1+k^{-1/2})}}={1\over 2^{k^{1/2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

General observation based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4688303/167197), if you let $$a_n = 1 + \frac{\ln(b_n)}{\ln(n)}$$ for some sequence $\{b_n\}$, then this series can be re-writtten as $$\sum \frac{1}{n\,b_n}\,,$$
the convergence/divergence of which is easier to think about.